# Error on ~$ sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I am trying to install a theme in Ubuntu 16.10 and I am getting error on sudo apt-get update
it shows:

```
awahab@awahab:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for awahab: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably have some kind of program that locks the APT files. This could be:

- Ubuntu software center installing something
- You changing your software sources
- The Software Update doing it's work

If you reboot the machine and issue that same command, what does happen?

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that another process is already using sudo. This could be any program that asked for a password when you opened it. Close all other programs and try again. If that doesn't work, reboot your computer and only open the terminal and run this command again.